# Is there a Python graphics library to represent floating point coordinates? (Gravity simulation)

Tags: python, graphics, simulation

I am trying to make a gravity simulation in Python3, I have objects which must move to represent the effects of gravity. Currently I am using pygame for this simualtion, but as my coordinates are floating point numbers (due to my calculation for new positions using a float for gravity) I would have to round them to integers and I am not too keen on losing accuracy.

Is there any python library/package that would be appropriate for such a simulation?

Answer (score 1):

I found a website with someone who seems to have done something similar to this using pygame [Here](https://www.thanassis.space/gravity.html) try it out. Hope it helps.

Comment: Oh wow, that's actually very detailled ! I wanted to avoid looking directly at source code of similar projects but I'll definitely look into this :)

Comment: @A.D yeah, I usually find that if I can’t do something myself I just look at someone else’s code for inspiration, the amount of time it’s saved me when making my projects.